# Cut elements of array in Swift 2

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have array of elements (it's a basic array). Type of array is String

`basicArray = [1710, 1725, 1740, 1755, 1810, 1825, 1840, 1855, 1925, 1955, 2020, 2050, 2120, 2150, 2220, 2250, 2320, 2350, 2430]`

I need to create two new arrays where each element of basicArray must be cut into two parts, for example:

```
array1 = [17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 20, 20....]
array2 = [10, 25, 40, 55, 10, 25, 40, 55, 25,55, 20, 50...]
```

How better to do it? Thank you for your advice!

Comment: how do you want to "cut" the arrays ? based on what ?

Comment: you haven't shown us how you're doing it so what is 'better'? if you haven't done it then you need to try and tell us what went wrong...

Comment: I know, that every element has 4 symbols. I need cut into two parts every element of array, so in new array1 I'll try have elements from 2 first symbols, and in array2 I'll try have element from 2 second symbols

Comment: Based on the formatting (lack of quotes) your array appears to be integers, not strings. If it really is an array of strings then the values should have quotes around them. @Eendje gave you a good solution if you array really contains strings. (voted)

Comment: @DuncanC True. But there's also `Type of array is String` in the first line. :)

Comment: @VadimNikolaev pls edit your questions so the format of your array is with strings instead of integers...

Comment: You should edit your question to make it clear what you mean (put the first 2 characters of every string in the first array, and the last 3 characters in the second array.) "Cut into 2 parts" is too vague.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
let basic = ["1710", "1725", "1740", "1755", "1810", "1825", "1840", "1855", "1925", "1955", "2020", "2050", "2120", "2150", "2220", "2250", "2320", "2350", "2430"]
let array1 = basic.map { String($0.characters.prefix(2)) }
let array2 = basic.map { String($0.characters.suffix(2)) }

print(array1)
print(array2)
```

Output:

```
["17", "17", "17", "17", "18", "18", "18", "18", "19", "19", "20", "20", "21", "21", "22", "22", "23", "23", "24"]
["10", "25", "40", "55", "10", "25", "40", "55", "25", "55", "20", "50", "20", "50", "20", "50", "20", "50", "30"]
```

Something like this?

Comment: @VadimNikolaev if this answer solved your problem, remember to accept it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Hints are in the code comments):

```
var basicArray = [1710, 1725, 1740, 1755, 1810, 1825, 1840, 1855, 1925, 1955, 2020, 2050, 2120, 2150, 2220, 2250, 2320, 2350, 2430]
var firstTwoDigitsArray = [Int]()
var lastTwoDigitsArray = [Int]()

for element in basicArray {

    // dividing by 100 shifts the numbers down by the first two digits
    firstTwoDigitsArray.append(element/100)

    // modulo 100 gets the last two digits 
    lastTwoDigitsArray.append(element%100)

}

print(firstTwoDigitsArray) // [17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24]
print(lastTwoDigitsArray) // [10, 25, 40, 55, 10, 25, 40, 55, 25, 55, 20, 50, 20, 50, 20, 50, 20, 50, 30]
```

Answer (score -2):

Swift has a built in method called `filter` which basically is a closure that iterates over all elements and lets you -- as the name suggests -- filter the elements based on a predicate:

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

let array1 = array.filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }
print(array1) // [2, 4, 6]
let array2 = array.filter { $0 % 2 == 1 }
print(array2) // [1,3,5]
```

You haven't made clear how you want those arrays to be *filtered*, so it's hard to explicitly give the answer that you might be looking for...